# VectorDrawable: Android loads xhdpi PNG's instead of the vector resource

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to use a `VectorDrawable` on API21, but Android loads the PNG resource from `xxhdpi` folder instead.
My current `res` structure as follows:

- res

  - drawable-xxhdpi

    - test_icon.png
  - drawable-21

    - test_icon.xml

And my XML layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/test_icon"/>
```

Are there any other ways to solve this? From my understanding Android will always pick the PNG resource, but if that's the case, how one can use `VectorDrawables` for `API21` and PNG for lower API's?

**[Update 1]**

If we use a `drawable-xxhdpi-21` resource folder, Android will pick the vector instead of the PNG resource. But that means we would have to have a copy (or symlink) of the file for other densities as well (e.g. `xhdpi`, `hdpi`, etc)

Comment: What about nodpi-21? Doesn't that solve it?

Comment: Come on, close the question

Comment: @pengrad unnecessary comment buddy...

Comment: You can avoid having the PNG file and use just the VectorDrawable on all Android versions, because the support library can get handle this case. Just use "app:srcCompat" instead of "app:src" and set the flag "vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true" inside the "defaultConfig" area of your app gradle file. The VectorDrawable should be in the "res/drawable" folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

drawable-anydpi-v21 is right for that

```
drawable-anydpi-v21/test_icon.xml
```

https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icons-for-android

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found is a bit of a hack but seems to work. Instead of putting your `VertorDrawable` xml files in each of the  bucket with the version, if you put them in `drawable-w1dp-v21` it takes the right resource and don't need to have multiple copies.

This is because, when deciding which resource to use, Android checks the density and after the minimum width density, which in this case is always gonna be more than 1dp :)

**Update:** as @pengrad mentions best to use the `anydpi` bucket. :)