# Use xxhdpi on xhdpi device

Tags: android, drawable, dpi

I created my app to support screens from `hdpi` to `xxxdpi` and everything was working perfect. Images were shown just like they're supposed to. But, now I have a problem with Xiaomi Mi Max 3. It has 6,9" display with a resolution of only `1080x2160` which  gives a ~350 dpi. That falls into `xhdpi` category (usually `720p` screens) and now my images are smaller then they should be. Is there any way to force the use of `drawable-xxhdpi` folder with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to Md.Abdullah I found a solution.
You cannot choose which folder of resources to use but you can use specific resource from a folder with `getDrawableForDensity()` method. This is what I did:

```
int width = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
int dpi = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
int imageID = R.drawable.YOURIMAGE;
if (width > VALUE && dpi < VALUE) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawableForDensity(imageId, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH);
//you will probably need to adjust width & height of your ImageView, but since the image
//will keep its aspect ratio, you only have to change width | heigth
        YOURIMAGEVIEW.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        YOURIMAGEVIEW.setMaxWidth(VALUE);
        YOURIMAGEVIEW.setImageDrawable(drawable);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just create another file like as:

drawable-xxxdpi/example.png

drawable-anydpi-v21/example.xml

and link your image file from anydpi xml code for supporting every screen size.
see more information from official website or visit [What Is The Difference Between -anydpi And -nodpi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156957/what-is-the-difference-between-anydpi-and-nodpi)

Comment: First, I'm looking for a way not to copy same resource. Second, that will mess up all the other devices with v21+. Third, I don't have a vector graphic, just a regular png. Thx anyway

Comment: This selecting process is automatically done by system. So you can't do this manually. But you can try some code flowing this link:-      https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.content.res.Resources&method=getDrawableForDensity